# Значение слова "премиальный"

Tags: значение-слов, семантика

Раньше слово "премиальный", насколько я знаю, употреблялось для обозначения чего-то, что получают в качестве премии. Например: премиальные выплаты, премиальные надбавки. Для обозначения продуктов высокого качества применялся оборот *продукт премиум-класса*. Но в последнее время появились *премиальные часы, автомобили* и т. д.

Правильно ли употреблять прилагательное "премиальный" для обозначения продуктов класса премиум?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грамота-ру считает  такое употребление слова ***премиальный*** допустимым.

```
Вопрос № 286631
```

Как правильно говорить при разговоре с клиентом: премиальный сорт кофе или кофе премиум класса?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Верны оба варианта: ***премиальный сорт кофе, кофе премиум-класса.***

Вопрос № 275374

Уважаемые специалисты портала, подскажите, пожалуйста, как оформить сочетание "Сорт премиум", когда речь идет о продуктах питания. Заключается ли слово "премиум" в кавычки?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Корректно без кавычек: ***сорт премиум, класс премиум.***

Пример: Наибольшей популярностью у покупателей **премиальных автомобилей** пользуется BMW 5-ой серии.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "премиальный" означает "с доплаченной премией". Только премию выплатят не вам. Когда продают премиальный кофе или автомобиль премиум-класса, за его продажу премию получает продавец, а не вы. Вы фактически доплачивает эту премию ему, как раз более высокой ценой кофе или авто

Comment: Можно предположить, что премию выплачивают покупателям, посредством того что продают автомобиль по такой низкой (хотя и высокой) цене.

Comment: Слово "премиум" маркетологами используется как манипуляция. Скорее всего по их задумке оно должно ассоциироваться у среднестатистического покупателя: с избранностью (посмотрите, какой я крутой, могу себе позволить премиальный сорт кофе или авто "А"-класса) и с высоким качеством (мол, премиальный сорт кофе не может быть невкусным или авто "А"-класса сломаться в принципе не может). Возможно в этом смысле всё перечисленное и будет как бы премией покупателю. Но в реальности ведь это далеко не всегда так. В реальности покупатель просто переплачивает за бренд товара с приставкой "премиум"